# What hashing method does the object.hashCode use?

Tags: php, hash, dart

I need to get the hash of an object to compare that with the hash stored on the server. The easiest way to get a hash on the client side seems to be `myObject.hashCode` but I wonder how I can reproduce that hash on the server side assuming I have the same object? Or to make this easier, assuming the object is a String.

Is dart using a wide-known method like MD5 that I can easily use in php or would I better use a different way?

Comment: What is your use case? A hashCode doesn't identify a specific instance. HashCode only guarantees that two identical values return the same hashCode but not that two different values have different hashCodes.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer i have a password which I want to not save in clear text in the database so I do not need this in my actual use case. But my question is out of curiousity because I am positive that there may be situations where you want to compare the serverside instance of an object with the clientside one without them being easily accessible to MITM attavks or similar. Of course, there are other ways to encrypt traffic, but why not ...

Comment: `.hashCode` isn't suitable for this use case. Two totally different objects can have the same hashCode. You should only use immutable fields for hashCode calculation. If the hashCode changes for an object previously inserted into a hashmap you can't retreive it anymore by key.

Comment: Thank you. I don't see the use of .hashCode then. What is it typically used for?

Comment: I guess a hashMap is the most common use case. A hashMap stores its values in buckets for faster access where the hashCode is used as key for the buckets. The main feature of hashCode is to have a good distribution over the possible values so that not all values end up in the same bucket which would defeat the purpose. See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table for more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `hashCode` getter in your classes with your custom implementation, to control how they are created.